# Fuel PHP Orm, join

Tags: php, database, orm, fuelphp

I have been playing with fuelphp lately and am trying something with the ORM.
Never used an ORM before so I think I don't understand very well.

My database consists of object types with multiple objects meta´s.

So I have three tables.

`object_types` which has multiple `object_types_meta` which is a join table to `objects_meta_type`

But I don't know how to convert this to the ORM. Can someone please point me in the correct direction?

I thought it would be:
`object_types` has many `object_types_meta` and then `object_types_meta` belongs to `objects_types` but what do I do with `object_meta_type`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `object_meta_type` belongs to `object_types_meta`

Comment: I find that the rails documentation for associations helps to understand a lot of how fuelphp's orm relationships work:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be using a `many to many` relationship with object_types_meta being the in between table?

http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/relations/many_many.html

Answer (score 0):

If the join table doesn't contain any extra columns except the two foreign keys, you should use a many-many relation, and use the join table as 'through' table.

If it does contain columns you need to access, you have to create a model for the join table too, and create two one-to-many relations from the join table to the two other models.